# Как подвинуть круг в следующем переключателе?

Tags: html, css, transition

Есть следующий переключатель

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот что получилось с ним сделать

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background: black;
}

.radio-btn {
  max-width: 40px;
  min-height: 16px;
  margin-top: 15px;
  margin-left: 15px;
}
.radio-btn input {
  display: none;
}
.radio-btn input:checked + label {
  background: #D012FF;
  box-shadow: 0 -18px 20px -12px #0B9090 inset;
}
.radio-btn input:checked + .circle {
  transform: translateX(3px);
}
.radio-btn .btn-field {
  transition: all 300ms;
  background: #D9D9D9;
  max-width: 40px;
  min-height: 16px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  display: grid;
  position: relative;
}
.radio-btn .btn-field .circle {
  position: absolute;
  top: -3px;
  left: -2.42px;
  width: 22.42px;
  height: 22.98px;
  background: linear-gradient(180deg, #A00BC5 0%, #1B5454 100%);
  border: 3px solid #FFFFFF;
  border-radius: 15px;
}

/*# sourceMappingURL=radio.css.map */
```

```html
<div class="radio-btn">
    <input type="radio" name="insertType" id="insertByUrl" value="url" checked>
    <label for="insertByUrl" class="btn-field">
        <div class="circle"></div>
    </label>
</div>

<div class="radio-btn">
    <input type="radio" name="insertType" id="insertByFile" value="file">
    <label for="insertByFile" class="btn-field">
        <div class="circle"></div>
    </label>
</div>
```

Как сделать так, чтобы кружок тоже двигался при переключении?

Comment: Вы сейчас серьёзно?

Answer (score 0):

#### Уточнение

Когда-то давно делал такой переключатель, так как часто понадобилось в проектах. Теперь из архивов достаю и они пыльные очень. Прошу строго не судить.

#### Решение

```css
body {
  background-color: rgb(30, 30, 30);
}

input[type="checkbox"]+label[role="checkbox"].toggle {
  cursor: pointer;
  aspect-ratio: 3;
  width: 30px;
  display: flex;
  border-radius: 50vmin;
  padding: 2px;
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}

input[type="checkbox"]+label[role="checkbox"].toggle>span.knob {
  aspect-ratio: 1;
  height: 100%;
  transform: scale(2);
  border-radius: inherit;
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: auto;
  background-color: rgb(200, 200, 200);
}

input[type="checkbox"]:checked+label[role="checkbox"] {
  background-color: hsl(285, 80%, 40%);
}

input[type="checkbox"]:checked+label[role="checkbox"].toggle>span.knob {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: 0;
}

input[type="checkbox"]:disabled+label[role="checkbox"] {
  filter: opacity(0.5);
}
```

```html
<input id="any-id" type="checkbox" hidden checked />
<label for="any-id" role="checkbox" class="toggle layer">
  <span class="knob"></span>
</label>
<br />
<input id="any-other-id" type="checkbox" hidden disabled />
<label for="any-other-id" role="checkbox" class="toggle layer">
  <span class="knob"></span>
</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background: black;
}

.radio-btn {
  max-width: 40px;
  min-height: 16px;
  margin-top: 15px;
  margin-left: 15px;
}
.radio-btn input {
  display: none;
}
.radio-btn input:checked + label {
  background: #D012FF;
  box-shadow: 0 -18px 20px -12px #0B9090 inset;
}

.radio-btn .btn-field {
  transition: all 300ms;
  background: #D9D9D9;
  max-width: 40px;
  min-height: 16px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  display: grid;
  position: relative;
}
.radio-btn .btn-field .circle {
  position: absolute;
  top: -3px;
  left: -2.42px;
  width: 22.42px;
  height: 22.98px;
  background: linear-gradient(180deg, #A00BC5 0%, #1B5454 100%);
  border: 3px solid #FFFFFF;
  border-radius: 15px;
}

.radio-btn .btn-field .circle {
  position: absolute;
  top: -3px;
  left: -2.42px;
  width: 22.42px;
  height: 22.98px;
  background: linear-gradient(180deg, #A00BC5 0%, #1B5454 100%);
  border: 3px solid #FFFFFF;
  border-radius: 15px;
}

.radio-btn input:checked + .btn-field > .circle{
  transform: translateX(20px);
}
```

```html
<div class="radio-btn">
    <input type="radio" name="insertType" id="insertByUrl" value="url" checked>
    <label for="insertByUrl" class="btn-field">
    <div class="circle"></div>
    </label>
</div>

<div class="radio-btn">
    <input type="radio" name="insertType" id="insertByFile" value="file">
    <label for="insertByFile" class="btn-field">
    <div class="circle"></div>
    </label>
    
</div>
```